# How to get divider component in JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jsplitpane

I want to get divider component in `JSplitPane`. I want to attach `MouseListener` to it.

How to get divider component of `JSplitPane`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

Initially:

```
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSPlitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panelOne, panelTwo);
pane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent propertyChangeEvent) {
        // some processing here
    }
});
```

---

Updated:

```
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panelOne, panelTwo);
BasicSplitPaneUI basicSplitPaneUI = (BasicSplitPaneUI) pane.getUI();
BasicSplitPaneDivider basicSplitPaneDivider = basicSplitPaneUI.getDivider();
basicSplitPaneDivider.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // some processing here
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't give me divider itself. I need it to add mouse listener.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to attach mouse listener to it.

Why do you need a MouseListener (there may be a better solution if we know the actual requirement)?

> I want to get divider component in JSplitPane.

You get the divider from the UI:

```
BasicSplitPaneUI ui = (BasicSplitPaneUI)splitPane.getUI();
BasicSplitPaneDivider divider = ui.getDivider();
```

Comment: When mouse is over divider, I shall resize left component to show file browser. And when file browser loses focus I hide this left component.

Comment: @Volodia, and I gave you the two line of code needed to get the component and yet you didn't accept the answer?